# Scroll base paging in gwt

Tags: gwt

```
For scroll base paging in gwt,i am using the scroll panel and its scroll event.
On scroll event, i have given the async call to fetch record from database.
```

question:-1)how can i restrict the scroll event for scroll up? 
 2)if the user is scrolling down, fetch data and display.It could be possible that the user has just scrolled up again and now he is normally scrolling down to see the previously loaded data? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollPanel has a method called `getVerticalScrollPosition`.  You can check to see if it is close to the bottom of the panel and fetch the results then.

The direction of the scroll may not be so important then, but you can calculate the scrolling velocity yourself by keeping track of the last scroll position and comparing it to the new scroll position.